# Get type of T where T :class from instance and pass it

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have the following code:

```
public List<string> GetTest([Service] IRepository<MyModel> repository, List<FilterDef> filter)
      {
    
          var fbuilder = create_filter<MyModel>(filter);

          return null;
      }
```

Where is defined as:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T :class
```

and

```
FilterBuilder<T> create_filter<T>(List<FilterDef> filter)
```

I would like to keep this generic and pass T from my repository to the create_filter method.
I came accros another post and figured out how to resolve T:

```
Type genericType = repository.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

However, now I am stuck how to pass on T to the create_filter method since T must be resolved before runtime.

Comment: Runtime will take care of resolving the type for you, `GetTest<T>(...){ create_filter<T>(...); }` should work

Comment: It's really unclear to me where you expect this to be generic - you talk about your repository code, but you haven't told us what that looks like. Is that what the `GetTest` method is from? That's not generic at the moment. Is the point that you *want* it to be generic? Please try to clarify your question. I'd also strongly advise you to rename `create_filter` to follow .NET naming conventions.